# Can I use the same disk to backup multiple Macs with Time Machine?

Tags: mac, time-machine

So I've been using an external hard drive to backup one of my Macs using Time Machine. Now I have another Mac that I feel the need to backup, but I don't want to buy a new hard drive, so I was wondering if I can use the same hard drive without reformatting it.

So basically can backups from multiple Macs co-exist on the same partition without interfering with each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they can. You can back up as many machines as you want with the same disk.

Just make sure you have enough space on the drive left. As far as I'm concerned you also don't have to fear one Mac deleting the old backups of another machine in case you run out of space. Time Machine will only delete old files from the machine it's currently running from.